# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}z^{n(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

> Find the radius of convergence of
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}z^{n(n+1)}$$
>
> And study what happens in the border.

Ok so I calculated $$\limsup \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}z^{n(n+1)}\right|^{1/n}=\limsup\left|\frac{z^{n(n+1)}}{n^2}\right|^{1/n}=\limsup \frac{|z|^{n+1}}{n^{2/n}}$$

And concluded that if $|z|>1$ the series diverges, if $|z|<1$ the series converges. So for $|z|=1$ im getting quite a hard time in trying to bound the partial sums. There are several problems of these type (in which the exponent of $z$ in the hidden power series is not just $n$) and I don't know how to bound the partial sums in the different cases. Can anybody help?

Comment: By the way, the sum should not start at $0$! Start at $n=1$, and imagine letting $z$ have norm $1$. Since $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, say by integral test, we have convergence.

Comment: I don't even need the integral test right? Just by saying $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}z^{n(n+1)} \right | = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left | \frac{1}{n^2} \right | = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ wich converges

Comment: Well, by now it is a standard fact that $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, so it is enough to assert it. But back a long time ago, you proved it, probably using the integral test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we  write the power series in the following form:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}z^{n(n+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kz^k$$
then
$$a_k=\begin{cases}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}, &\text{ if }k\text{ is of the form }n(n+1)\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then to find the radius of convergence we need to calculate
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}|a_k|^{\frac{1}{k}}$$
It follows that
$$\limsup_{k\to\infty}|a_k|^{\frac{1}{k}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|^{\frac{1}{n(n+1)}}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}n^{-\frac{2}{n(n+1)}}=1$$
So the radius of convergence is $1$.

Furthermore, if $|z|=1$, then
$$\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}z^{n(n+1)}\right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
Thus the series is absolutely convergent for $|z|=1$.